# Displaying Image from firebase cloud firestore by download URL

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making an Android App in which i have some user Accounts and linked with each is some data. The data also has a download URL associated with a image stored in Firebase Storage.

I know how to retrieve data from Firebase cloud firestore so I will retrieve value of the download url in app
by the line

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference user = db.collection("School").document("Accouts").collection("students").document(name);

        user.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                    String img_url = (String) doc.get("image");
                }
            }
        });
```

but I don't know how to load that image and display in ImageView

**I want to do it without using external library**

The database is

[image]

Comment: you can use Glide or Picasso or any other lib to display it.

Comment: @Ticherhaz Is there a easy way without these libraries

Comment: It doesn't really matter that you're using Cloud Firestore or Cloud Storage.  You still just have a URL to load into an ImageView, and that's a *really* old problem that's been solved many times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Glide. https://github.com/bumptech/glide.

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(img_url)
     .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load your image.

> Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

**How to use:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);

Glide.with(this)
.load("your URL goes here")
.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load image using **Picasso**

add dependency to your **app/build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

then you can load your image like below

```
Picasso.get().load(yourImageUrl).into(imageView);
```

For more info check [Piccasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: there are so much flaw with `picasso`. It's better if you follow [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?authuser=0#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) and firebase expires url token so each time it needs to revoke

Comment: I am using it since last year and it didn't gimme a chance to criticize it.   Everyone has it's own preferences

Comment: i am not saying it's bad or something wrong with it but it will take time to get url and other stuff to show image if you know what i means. The above question was get image url by using storage reference and then show image better if he use storage ref to show image will be better and fast